# Multi-level Categories in Wagtail

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, wagtail

I always make sure I have tried every possible avenue before coming on here for advice.

That said, here is what I am currently struggling with; creating multi-level/nested categories. As an aside, it will be nice if the wagtail core developers can implement an easy way for multi-level category creation, without us having to write some vanilla-django hack for it.

I have been working on this application for a few weeks, everything runs smoothly, except now, there's a business decision for a nested category to be implemented.

My initial M.O was to create a ServiceCategoryIndex Page, a ServiceCategoryPage then make the ServiceIndex Page a descendant or orderable to the ServiceCategoryIndex Page as ServiceCategoryPage, Which just doesn't seem right.

After a couple of iteration, I went back to my default model, then tried the url of the category using views and url like vanilla-django, the problem with is, I am not able to query the foreign key with a through relationship on the template, so I still can't get the content of the service page as a list queryset rendered out.

Here're my model codes below, any suggestion or work around on this will be absolutely helpful. P.S: I am almost at the point of re-writing the whole project in vanilla-django, giving I don't find a solution within the next few days.

```
def get_service_context(context):
    context['all_categories'] = ServiceCategory.objects.all()
    context['root_categories'] = ServiceCategory.objects.filter(
    parent=None,
    ).prefetch_related(
    'children',
    ).annotate(
    service_count=Count('servicepage'),
    )
    return context

class ServiceIndexPage(Page):
    header_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    sub_heading = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    body = RichTextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def get_context(self, request, category=None, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ServiceIndexPage, self).get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)

        services = ServicePage.objects.child_of(self).live().order_by('-first_published_at').prefetch_related('categories', 'categories__category')
        if category is None:
            if request.GET.get('category'):
                category = get_object_or_404(ServiceCategory, slug=request.GET.get('category'))
        if category:
            if not request.GET.get('category'):
                category = get_object_or_404(ServiceCategory, slug=category)
            services = services.filter(categories__category__name=category)

        # Pagination
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        page_size = 10
        if hasattr(settings, 'SERVICE_PAGINATION_PER_PAGE'):
            page_size = settings.SERVICE_PAGINATION_PER_PAGE

        if page_size is not None:
            paginator = Paginator(services, page_size)  # Show 10 services per page
            try:
                services = paginator.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:
                services = paginator.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:
                services = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


        context['services'] = services
        context['category'] = category
        context = get_service_context(context)

        return context


@register_snippet
class ServiceCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True, verbose_name=_('Category Name'))
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=250)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name="children")
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    description = RichTextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']
        verbose_name = _("Service Category")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Service Categories")

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        FieldPanel('parent'),
        FieldPanel('description'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def clean(self):
        if self.parent:
            parent = self.parent
            if self.parent == self:
                raise ValidationError('Parent category cannot be self.')
            if parent.parent and parent.parent == self:
                raise ValidationError('Cannot have circular Parents.')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            slug = slugify(self.name)
            count = ServiceCategory.objects.filter(slug=slug).count()
            if count > 0:
                slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, count)
            self.slug = slug
        return super(ServiceCategory, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class ServiceCategoryServicePage(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(ServiceCategory, related_name="+", verbose_name=_('Category'))
    page = ParentalKey('ServicePage', related_name='categories')
    panels = [
        FieldPanel('category'),
    ]



class ServicePage(Page):
     header_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
        verbose_name=_('Header image')
    )
    service_title = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    body = StreamField([
        ('h1', CharBlock(icon="title", classanme="title")),
        ('h2', CharBlock(icon="title", classanme="title")),
        ('h3', CharBlock(icon="title", classanme="title")),
        ('h4', CharBlock(icon="title", classanme="title")),
        ('h5', CharBlock(icon="title", classanme="title")),
        ('h6', CharBlock(icon="title", classanme="title")),
        ('paragraph', RichTextBlock(icon="pilcrow")),
        ('aligned_image', ImageBlock(label="Aligned image", icon="image")),
        ('pullquote', PullQuoteBlock()),
        ('raw_html', RawHTMLBlock(label='Raw HTML', icon="code")),
        ('embed', EmbedBlock(icon="code")),
])
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    service_categories = models.ManyToManyField(ServiceCategory, through=ServiceCategoryServicePage, blank=True)

    feed_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
        verbose_name=_('Feed image')
    )

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('body'),
        index.SearchField('service_title'),
        index.SearchField('title'),]


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.url


    def get_service_index(self):
        # Find closest ancestor which is a service index
        return self.get_ancestors().type(ServiceIndexPage).last()


    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ServicePage, self).get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context['services'] = self.get_service_index().serviceindexpage
        context = get_service_context(context)
        return context

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Service page')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Services pages')

    parent_page_types = ['services.ServiceIndexPage']


ServicePage.content_panels = [
    FieldPanel('title', classname="full title"),
    FieldPanel('service_title'),
    ImageChooserPanel('header_image'),
    FieldPanel('date'),
    InlinePanel('categories', label=_("Categories")),
    StreamFieldPanel('body'),
    ImageChooserPanel('feed_image'),
```

]

Comment: How many levels of nesting do you need? Also, do you need to select the category 'groups' or just the lowest level 'category'?

Comment: Ideally the levels of nesting should be as much as possible, but 2 will be good. And yea category groups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been working on a similar issue - except we are calling them `Topic` instead of `Category` but hopefully this helps you out.

## Summary of Solution

- Use the [Django-Treebeard library](http://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to manage your trees, they can be nested up to 63 levels deep and will give you full access to the api for things like `get_children` or `is_root`.
- You will need to override some behaviour for creating and 'moving' nodes, this is best done by the [`base_form_class` override](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#custom-edit-handler-forms).
- I have used [ModelAdmin](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html) for this but it should work just as well if the are snippets, but ModelAdmin gives you more control for the future if you wanted to add more complex editing.
- Finally, you can then link these topics/categories to your pages with a ForeignKey or some other relational link.
- Caveats: No reordering of child nodes other than alphabetical in this example, this can be added but it is a bit more complicated as you need a UI for it - hence using ModelAdmin. Also, you should never let the user delete the root, it will delete all nodes.
- [Django Treebeard Caveats](http://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/caveats.html) - worth reading

## 1 - Building the Model

I have a dedicated `Topics` app, but you can put this in any models.py. See comments throughout that explain the code.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.db import models

from treebeard.mp_tree import MP_Node

from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import ModelAdmin
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.forms import WagtailAdminModelForm


# This is your main 'node' model, it inherits mp_node
# mp_node is short for materialized path, it means the tree has a clear path
class Topic(MP_Node):
    """
        Topics can be nested and ordered.
        Root (id 1) cannot be deleted, can be edited.
        User should not edit path, depth, numchild directly.
    """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    is_selectable = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # means selectable by pages
    # any other fields for the Topic/Category can go here
    # eg. slug, date, description

    # may need to rework node_order_by to be orderable
    # careful - cannot change after initial data is set up
    node_order_by = ['name']

    # just like any model in wagtail, you will need to set up panels for editing fields
    panels = [
        FieldPanel('parent'),  # parent is not a field on the model, it is built in the TopicForm form class
        FieldPanel('name', classname='full'),
        FieldPanel('is_selectable'),
    ]

    # this is just a convenience function to make the names appear with lines
    # eg root | - first child
    def name_with_depth(self):
        depth = '— ' * (self.get_depth() - 1)
        return depth + self.name
    name_with_depth.short_description = 'Name'

    # another convenience function/property - just for use in modeladmin index
    @property
    def parent_name(self):
        if not self.is_root():
            return self.get_parent().name
        return None

    # a bit of a hacky way to stop users from deleting root
    def delete(self):
        if self.is_root():
            raise PermissionDenied('Cannot delete root topic.')
        else:
            super(Topic, self).delete()

    # pick your python string representation
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name_with_depth()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_with_depth()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Topic'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Topics'


# this class is the form class override for Topic
# it handles the logic to ensure that pages can be moved
# root pages need to be treated specially
# including the first created item always being the root
class TopicForm(WagtailAdminModelForm):

    # build a parent field that will show the available topics
    parent = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        required=True,
        empty_label=None,
        queryset=Topic.objects.none(),
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TopicForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = kwargs['instance']
        all = Topic.objects.all()
        is_root = False

        if len(all) == 0 or instance.is_root():
            # no nodes, first created must be root or is editing root
            is_root = True

        if is_root:
            # disable the parent field, rename name label
            self.fields['parent'].empty_label = 'N/A - Root Node'
            self.fields['parent'].disabled = True
            self.fields['parent'].required = False
            self.fields['parent'].help_text = 'Root Node has no Parent'
            self.fields['name'].label += ' (Root)'
        else:
            # sets the queryset on the parent field
            # ensure that they cannot select the existing topic as parent
            self.fields['parent'].queryset = Topic.objects.exclude(
                pk=instance.pk)
            self.fields['parent'].initial = instance.get_parent()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        parent = self.cleaned_data['parent']
        instance = super(TopicForm, self).save(commit=False)
        all = Topic.objects.all()

        is_new = instance.id is None
        is_root = False
        if is_new and len(all) == 0:
            is_root = True
        elif not is_new and instance.is_root():
            is_root = True

        # saving / creating
        if is_root and is_new and commit:
            # adding the root
            instance = Topic.add_root(instance=instance)
        elif is_new and commit:
            # adding a new child under the seleced parent
            instance = parent.add_child(instance=instance)
        elif not is_new and instance.get_parent() != parent and commit:
            # moving the instance to under a new parent, editing existing node
            # must use 'sorted-child' - will base sorting on node_order_by
            instance.move(parent, pos='sorted-child')
        elif commit:
            # no moving required, just save
            instance.save()

        return instance


# tell Wagtail to use our form class override
Topic.base_form_class = TopicForm


class TopicAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Topic
    menu_icon = 'radio-empty'
    menu_order = 200
    add_to_settings_menu = False
    list_display = ['name_with_depth', 'parent_name']
    search_fields = ['name']
```

## 2 - Register the modeladmin function in `wagtail_hooks.py`

This ensures that the TopicAdmin in the previous code is used in Wagtail Admin. You will know it works as it will appear on the left admin sidebar [modeladmin register docs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html#registering-multiple-classes-in-one-wagtail-hooks-py-file).

```
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import modeladmin_register
from .models import TopicAdmin


modeladmin_register(TopicAdmin)
```

## 3 - Migrate & Create First Topic

Now would be a good time to make migrations and run your migrate, remember that `node_order_by` is not easy to change after you have built your model. If you want to add custom ordering of children eg. reordering capacity or ordering by some other field, do this before you migrate.

Then go into admin and create the first root node.

## 4 - Link to your Pages

Here is a quick and nasty example, letting you link one topic to a page without anything fancy. Note that we are limiting choices here, this can be extended to do more complicated limiting based on the fields you have set in Topic.

```
topic = models.ForeignKey(
    'topics.Topic',
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    limit_choices_to={'is_selectable': True},
    related_name='blog_page_topic',
)
```

## 5 - Room for Improvement

- The topic string representation always contains the dashes to show its 'depth', this is a bit ugly when seen elsewhere. It would be better to use an extended field type and build this representation only when needed.
- As mentioned, no ability to reorder child nodes manually, you can create custom buttons in model admin so it would be possible to add buttons to move up/ move down and work through that way.
- Example code, so probably a few rough edges but should be enough to get you started. I have tested this on Wagtail 1.13 in the demo application and it works.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth putting a note that there is ongoing work for a `Collection hierarchy` but this would be more for Images/Documents.

It has been flagged for the 2.0 release.

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/3407